# How to pass a parameter to a SQL Job that will execute a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-agent-job

I have the below code (only the portion that is needed)

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'SomeStep', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'exec [dbo].[PORT_Insert_Record] ''https://localhost''',  
        @database_name=N'MyDatabase', 
        @flags=0
```

Now, I want to pass the `https://localhost` value into a variable and pass to the stored procedure (for some reason I cannot pass it inside the SP).

So I tried

```
DECLARE @domainName varchar(max)
DECLARE @sp varchar(max)
SET @domainName ='https://localhost:'
SET @sp ='exec [dbo].[PORT_Insert_Record]' + @domainName

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'InsertRecordIntoResellerOpportunities', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=@sp,  
        @database_name=N'MyDatabase',  
        @flags=0
```

but it is not working. I also search in the net for any idea/syntax etc.. but no luck as of now.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is is **NOT WORKING** - do you get an error?? If so: **what error**?? Is it running but not doing what you expect it to do?? Then: what **is** it doing vs. what did you **expect** ...... you need to provide more detail here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what's that `@ReturnCode` doing there? is it declared somewhere?

I tried this on a new job and it worked:

```
DECLARE @domainName varchar(max)
DECLARE @sp varchar(max)
SET @domainName ='https://localhost:'
SET @sp ='exec [dbo].[PORT_Insert_Record]' + @domainName

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=N'a756bfcb-2abf-4d7a-a871-85e234e7ef53', @step_name=N'Step 1', 
            @step_id=1, 
            @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
            @on_success_action=1, 
            @on_fail_action=2, 
            @retry_attempts=0, 
            @retry_interval=0, 
            @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
            @command=@sp, 
            @database_name=N'master', 
            @flags=0
    GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to double quote the quotation marks

```
SET @domainName ='https://localhost:' 
SET @sp ='exec [dbo].[PORT_Insert_Record] ''' + @domainName  + ''''
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write any information into your command script. Jobs have their own sessions. How they will know what was your parameters

Here is an example

```
--here is your existing parameters
declare @dateparam date = '2017-10-19'
declare @intparam int= 100
declare @stringparam nvarchar(20)= 'hello'

--now start write you sql job command
declare @command nvarchar(max)
set @command  = N'declare @dateparam date =' + CAST(@dateparam AS NVARCHAR(20)) + CHAR(13)
--+ CHAR(13) IS FOR LINEBREAK
set @command  = @command  + N'declare @intparam date =' + CAST(@intparam AS NVARCHAR(20)) + CHAR(13)
set @command  = @command  + N'declare @stringparam nvarchar(20) =' + @stringparam  + CHAR(13)
set @command  = @command  + N'exec dbo.my_store_procedure @dateparam, @intparam, @stringparam'

--NOW YOUR COMMAND HAVE ALL informations
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=N'a756bfcb-2abf-4d7a-a871-85e234e7ef53', @step_name=N'Step 1', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=@command, 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
```